# Optimizing Goldbach Conjecture algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, time

I did a Goldbach conjecture exercise and got it to work. It's pretty slow though and I was wondering how I could optimize it.

```
number = int(input("Enter your number >> "))
print("\nCalculating...")
if number % 2 == 0: #Only even numbers
    primes = primenums(number) #returns all prime numbers <= input number
    addend1 = primes[0]
    addend2 = primes[0]

    while addend1 + addend2 != number:
        if primes.index(addend2) + 1 == len(primes):
            addend2 = primes[primes.index(addend1) + 1]
            addend1 = primes[primes.index(addend1) + 1]
        else:
            addend2 = primes[primes.index(addend2) + 1]
```

Right now, up to 10.000 the algorithm is pretty fast, but at 100.000 it takes about 5 seconds to finish. Is that just how it is or could I make it faster?

Comment: For starters, replace `primes.index(addend2) + 1 == len(primes)` with `primes[-2] == addend2`. In general, try to reduce calls to `index` as much as possible.

Comment: more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier/faster to check for every prime number `p<n` if `n-p` is prime.

Answer (score 0):

### Just don't check for prime until you have to do it.

It would be faster to not generate an index of primes first.  Only check for primes if you have to check.  This code will do a check for 1,234,567,812,345,678 in about a second using my homegrown IsPrime() that I found somewhere.  Milliseconds if you use GMPY2.isprime()

The trick is to never check evens for prime, and skip many of the odds since the primes occur in gaps.  The worst case I have seen took about 150 calls to IsPrime.  Building a list of primes or a sieve to trillions takes a while.  i just skipped that part.

```
# Goldbach's Conjecture tester. 
import sys
from gmpy2 import is_prime
# or use home grown IsPrime()
def IsPrime(n): 
        if (n == 2 or n == 3): 
            return True 
        if (n <= 1 or n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0): 
            return False 
        for i  in range(5, int(n**.5)+1,  6): 
            if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0): 
                return False 
        return True 

def goldbach(number):
    if number == 4:
        print("\n2 + 2 = 4\n")
        return
    elif IsPrime(number - 3):
        print(f"\n3 + {number-3:,} = {number}\n")
        return  
    else:
        for p in range(5, number, 6): # just odds after 3 
            if IsPrime(p) and IsPrime(number-p): 
                print(f"\n{p:,} + {number-p:,} = {number:,}\n")
                return
            elif IsPrime(p+2) and IsPrime(number-(p+2)):
                print(f"\n{p+2:,} + {number-(p+2):,} = {number:,}\n")
                return
        raise Exception(f"Found a counter-example to the Goldbach conjecture: {number}")

if __name__=="__main__":
        N = 1
        args = len(sys.argv)
        if args > 1:
                N = int(sys.argv[1])
        print("This is a test of Goldbach's Conjecture that for all even integers")
        print("greater than 2 there are two primes that add up to that even number.\n")
        while (N < 3 or N%2):
                N = int(input("Please enter an even number > 3 to check with Goldbach's Conjecture> "))

        goldbach(N)
```